# After suspending the monitor does not turn on

Tags: 18.04, suspend, display, monitor, hibernate

I tried to suspend and hibernate the desktop but when I try to wake it up I can hear the <del>cpu</del> fun on but the monitor turns black and nothing appears, I don't know what to do, I tried using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and nothing

```
lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

sudo lshw -C display
*-display                 
       descrição: VGA compatible controller
       produto: Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770]
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:01:00.0
       versão: 00
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuração: driver=radeon latency=0
       recursos: irq:31 memória:e0000000-efffffff memória:fbdc0000-fbddffff porta de E/S:ee00(tamanho=256) memória:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm sorry but this is a bit unclear (at least to me). Would you be so kind as to [edit] your post to include the output of `lsb_release -d` and `sudo lshw -C display`? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Do you have a laptop? What make and model? BTW you are not hearing the CPU but either the Fan or Hard Drive.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have this problem on my Dell Inspiron 1000 series with an OEM-installed Ubuntu. I've found that support for actual hibernation is pretty sketchy in Ubuntu, at least with 16.04. As for suspending, I have found that the black frozen screen problem happens mostly when I "half close" the laptop for more than a half second or if my hand slips while opening it when it closes again. It probably confuses the ACPI manager. My only advice, which has worked for me, is just be very careful when opening or closing the lid.